# Jupyterlab: RuntimeError npm dependencies failed to install

Tags: cmd, npm, jupyter

En la pagina de vpython dicen que luego de instalar node.js, debo ejecutar en el terminal:

```
jupyter labextension install vpython
```

pero luego de hacerlo me salta el error:

```
<pre>
C:\Users\daniel koval>jupyter labextension install vpython
/Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1238, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 6547: character maps to <undefined>

An error occured.
IndexError: list index out of range
See the log file for details:  C:\Users\DANIEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jupyterlab-debug-qlat93mo.log
</pre>
```

y no se como solucionarlo. espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

dejo tambien lo que dice el archivo log:

Node v10.16.3

```
"C:\Program Files\node.js\npm.CMD" pack vpython
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
yield

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 82, in start
ans = self.run_task()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 103, in run_task
for arg in self.extra_args

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 103, in <listcomp>
for arg in self.extra_args

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 316, in install_extension
return handler.install_extension(extension)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 517, in install_extension
info = self._install_extension(extension, tempdir)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 1373, in _install_extension
info = self._extract_package(extension, tempdir)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 1441, in _extract_package
ret = self._run([which('npm'), 'pack', source], cwd=tempdir)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 1610, in _run
return proc.wait()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 96, in wait
out, _ = proc.communicate(timeout=.1)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 939, in communicate
stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1288, in _communicate
stdout = stdout[0]

IndexError: list index out of range

Exiting application: jupyter
```

Comment: Puede postear el contenido del log file?